# Why is OpenJDK Docker Container ignoring Memory Limits in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, wildfly, openjdk-11

I am running several Java Applications with the Docker image [jboss/wildfly:20.0.1.Final](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly) on Kubernetes 1.19.3. Wildfly server is running in OpenJDK 11 so the jvm is supporting container memory limits (cgroups).

If I set a memory limit this limit is totally ignored by the container when running in Kubernetes. But it is respected on the same machine when I run it in plain Docker:

**1. Run Wildfly in Docker with a memory limit of 300M:**

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name java-wildfly-test -p 8080:8080 -e JAVA_OPTS='-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0' -m=300M jboss/wildfly:20.0.1.Final
```

verify Memory usage:

```
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                 CPU %        MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %       NET I/O       BLOCK I/O     PIDS
515e549bc01f        java-wildfly-test    0.14%        219MiB / 300MiB       73.00%      906B / 0B     0B / 0B       43
```

As expected the container will NOT exceed the memory limit of 300M.

**2. Run Wildfly in Kubernetes with a memory limit of 300M:**

Now I start the same container within kubernetes.

```
$ kubectl run java-wildfly-test --image=jboss/wildfly:20.0.1.Final --limits='memory=300M' --env="JAVA_OPTS='-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0'"
```

verify memory usage:

```
$ kubectl top pod java-wildfly-test
NAME                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
java-wildfly-test   1089m        441Mi
```

The memory limit of 300M is totally ignored and exceeded immediately.

Why does this happen? Both tests can be performed on the same machine.

**Answer**

The reason for the high values was an incorrect output of the Metric data received from Project [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus). After uninstalling the kube-projemet and installing instead the [metric-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) all data was display correctly using kubctl top. It shows now the same values as docker stats. I do not know why kube-prometheus did compute wrong data. In fact it was providing the double values for all memory data.

Comment: I suspect that Docker and Kubelet run with different cgroup drivers. How can I check this?

Comment: What distribution of kubernetes are you running?

Comment: I installed kubernetes on self hosted nodes running on Debian Buster.

Comment: which docker version are you using?

Comment: I am using docker version 19.03.12. But now I assume my problem is that docker and kubelet are using different cgroupDriver. Can this be the root of the strange behavior?

Comment: I added my own answer. The reason was a wrong output from kube-prometheus. Using kubernetes metric-server solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I`m placing this answer as community wiki since it might be helpful for the community. Kubectl top was displying incorrect data. OP solved the problem with uninstalling the kube-prometheus stack and installing the metric-server.

> The reason for the high values was an incorrect output of the Metric
> data received from Project kube-prometheus. After uninstalling the
> kube-projemet and installing instead the metric-server all data was
> display correctly using kubectl top. It shows now the same values as
> docker stats. I do not know why kube-prometheus did compute wrong
> data. In fact it was providing the double values for all memory data.